# How do I reset Grafana dashboard data every day

Tags: prometheus, grafana

So I have server running 24/7, but I would like to only view data from 07:00 am and until the end of the day. I have my absolute time range set to: From now/d+7h To Now. This will only show me data from that point, but all counters will still remain the same (and increasing) as before. I also have time variables to set the interval to 1 hour, but this still shows data before that hour.

How would I go about resetting all metrics every day, without restarting the server? It is supposed to be a dashboard for our department to view live data from the start of the work day, and nothing from the day before.

Am I missing something obvious?

Data source is Prometheus

EDIT:
Maybe there are some query potions to only show data from the past hour or from a specific time? For like a Stat panel.

Comment: What counters do you need to reset? Could you add an example?

Comment: When you say dashboards, are you using grafana or some custom tool? If you provide a little more information about the setup we might be able to help!

Comment: @Crashtein Well these are counters that record the amount of events happening. There are thousands of those each day, and it would be nice to be able to reset them back to 0 at some point in the beginning of the day

Comment: @StephenDunne As stated in the title its about Grafana yes! :D My setup is based on scala (java) with spring and micrometer (PrometheusMeterRegistry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `changes( )` function on the target metric, and pass in the `$__range` variable which is calculated as `to - from` so it will use your preset date range.

```
changes(your_metric[$__range])
```